# How to define a import python package inside a module to a jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, import, jupyter-notebook, module, package

I have created a python module named text_cleaning.py stored into a src folder at the root of my projet:

```
def sub_step(df):
    df["text_clean"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
    df["text_clean"] = df["text_clean"].apply(lambda x: contractions.fix(x))
    return df
```

When I import it inside my jupyter notebook, the first step "lower" works.
And the second step contractions do not work.

My jupyter notebook (stored at the root of my projet):

```
import pandas as pd
import contractions
import src.text_cleaning

data = {'text': ["I miss him. Can't wait to celebrate the Tar"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

res = src.text_cleaning.sub_step(tweets[['text']])
res.iloc[0]
```

The output is :

```
text          I miss him.  Can't wait to celebrate the Tar
text_clean    i miss him.  can't wait to celebrate the tar
```

As you can see, all caracter have been lower but contracted word are again contracted.

The good return should have been :
i miss him.  can not wait to celebrate the tar

Maybe you can help. Thanks

You can see more details above

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
from .. import contractions
```

In your text_cleaning.py file.

‘..’ will look in the parent directory. If I’ve understood the folder structure from the explanation.

Comment: I had to add import contractions into the module text_cleaning.py

Comment: @ahmedaao good stuff